# i have a Vue JS template how to create toggle animation?

Tags: jquery, animation, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How to create transition animation on change class `fa-toggle-off` with `fa-toggle-on`

i have this code

```js
Vue.component('ios-button', {
    template: '#iosButton',
    data:function(){
      return {
        toggled:true,
        label:'',
      }
    },
    methods:{
      change:function(){
        this.toggled=!this.toggled;
        this.$emit('change');
      }
    }
  });
new Vue({
  el:"#square",
  data:{
    show:true,
  },
  methods:{
    checkIfCheched:function(){
      this.show=!this.show;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.square{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color:red;
}
#square{
  height:110px;

}
#square span{
  font-size:25px;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition: all 0.9s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id='square' class='text-center'>
    <ios-button v-on:change='checkIfCheched'></ios-button>
    <div class='square' v-show='show'>
    </div>
</div>
<template id="iosButton">
     <span class="fa toggle" v-bind:class="{'fa-toggle-on': toggled, 'fa-toggle-off': !toggled, 'text-success': toggled, 'text-muted': !toggled}" v-on:click="change"><span class="toggle-label">{{label}}</span></span> 
</template>
```

[jsfiddle my example](https://jsfiddle.net/d2xog757/4/)

Comment: See the [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html) and this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d2xog757/5/)

Comment: @RoyJ no square , button

Comment: You will need to have separate elements for each state of the toggle button so one can fade out and the other can fade in. You will not be able to have the button move smoothly from one side to the other because there is no button, there are just two icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your toggle contains of two font icons, so it's not possible to animate part of font icon.

It's like to animate letter "A" to "V" - just flip letter vertically and remove middle line of "A". (Not possible)

```
Here is example of correct implementation of animated toggle button.
```

[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/c84v6nsk/)